# protractor checking value of a javascript global variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I've got an angular 1 application where HTML has a little code snippet that declares global variable at the very beginning:

```
pathLanguage = "...";
```

The value of this variable depends on the URL given (parameters of the URL determine value of this variable). I would like to use `protractor` to check that value. Given the URL, how can I achieve that with protractor? Is it possible at all?

```
it("Open page", () => {
  browser.get(myURL);
  // ?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `executeScript` to get the variable:

```
it("Open page", () => {
  browser.get(myURL);
  expect(browser.executeScript("return window.pathLanguage;")).toEqual(...);
});
```